# How do I pass an array from one controller to another? Getting error Call to a member function has() on null

Tags: arrays, symfony, controller

Im trying to get $data from profileData function from First Controller and render it into html in Second Controller. I couldnt get pass through the error "Call to a member function has() on null". How do I fix this?

Here is the function that is stated in the First Controller.

```
public function profileData(Request $request, $uuid){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $currentUser = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
        $customerRepo = $em->getRepository('CoreEntity:SubscribedCustomer');
        $subscribedCustomer = $customerRepo->findOneBy(array('customer' => $uuid, 'consultant' => $currentUser->getId()));
        $customer = $subscribedCustomer->getCustomer();
        $age = 'N/A';
        $dob = $customer->getDateOfBirth();

        if ($dob) {
            $birthYear = $customer->getDateOfBirth()->format('Y');
            $yearNow = date('Y');
            $age = $yearNow - $birthYear;
            $dob = $customer->getDateOfBirth()->format('Y-m-d');
        } else {
            $dob = "";
        }
        if ($customer->getStatus() === 1) {
            $status = "Active";
        } else {
            $status = "Inactive";
        }
        $data = array(
            'firstName' => $customer->getFirstName(),
            'lastName' => $customer->getLastName(),
            'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
            'phoneNum' => $customer->getPhoneNumber(),
            'gender' => $customer->getGender(),
            'age' => $age,
            'status' => $status,
            'dob' => $dob
        );
    }
```

In the Second Controller, I want to render the data in

```
/**
 * @Route("/client/{uuid}/basic_health/bmi", name="client_bh_bmi")
 */
 public function basicHealthBmiAction($uuid)
 {
   $this->checkWebModuleAccess(WebModuleCode::MANAGE_CLIENT);
   $profileData = $this->get('client_profile_data')->profileData();
        return $this->render('AppBundle:client/health_record/basic_health:bmi.html.twig', array(
            'customer' => $data
        ));
    }
```

In services.yml :

```
services:
  client_profile_data:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\FirstController
```

Comment: Hard to know where to start.  Controller actions are designed to accept a request as input and return a response.  You don't call one from another.  All I can suggest is that you work through the getting started portions of the docs to get a feel for how Symfony apps are built.

Answer (score 1):

Though not very common, you can also forward to another controller internally with the forward() method provided by the AbstractController class.

Instead of redirecting the user's browser, this makes an "internal" sub-request and calls the defined controller. The forward() method returns the Response object that is returned from that controller

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html

Comment: But what if I want to call the array to many different functions (like into basicHealthBmiAction2, basicHealthBmiAction3, etc...) ?

Comment: First: If you want the $data array to be rendered by another controller action forwarding it should be the way to go. 
If you need to render the same array by different actions then you would have a conditional if/switch that forwards it to different actions.